# Does HTML5's SVG has a hidden surface removal feature/library?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, svg

So, in HTML5, I understand how SVG differs from Canvas in that SVG is declarative and Canvas is imperative.  It occurred to me that an even better declarative technology could be used to define shapes and then declare a viewpoint and let the browser figure the hidden surfaces to remove.

After some Googling I haven't found much, there is this link

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/

but this is not much help.

Is there a javascript library to do hidden surface removal on a new extended standard brewing?

So as an example use case, I want to define a cube as 12 edges, declare such opacity on the surfaces (so as not to wireframe it) and let the browser figure not to display the "back" surfaces.

Comment: You should just render from back to forth.

Comment: @Bálint, that's ingenious!  But how do you know what's at the back?  Kind of what the browser/library to figure that out.

Comment: Lemme post an answer

Comment: SVG and canvas are 2D technologies, not 3D. If you've a 3D requirement perhaps you should look at webGL

Comment: @Robert: thanks for steer.

Comment: @Robert I've proven many times on codepen, that [you don't need 3d technologys to make 3d](http://codepen.io/mcdorli/pen/LkdoZo), also, WebGL is not a 3d ApI, it can't draw 3d out of box

Comment: @balint indeed you don't it's just harder and more tedious when you have to do everything yourself. You're

Comment: @Robert not by much actually. But it's way more slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions when you want to render 3d. First is to render every triangle/quad from back to forth.

This can be usually done by calculating the middle of a shape by averaging the vertices' position, then sort the triangles based on the z coordinate.

After you sorted it, you render them in order.

The other solution is basically what you're looking for. You need to calculate the normal vectors by using cross product on 2 side vectors. When you draw the cube, you need to use dot product on the triangle's normal and the camera's direction vector, and if this value is less than or equal to 0 (the angle between the 2 vectors is more than 90°), then don't draw the triangle.

Comment: This is a very clever answer but I think I've messed up on the question.  As comment from Robert Longson indicates, I'm using wrong technology, I ought to be using WebGL not an inherently 2D tech like SVG.  I will accept this an answer and accept closure on this.  Thanks anyway Bálint.

Comment: @SMeaden [You don't need 3d technologys to draw 3d](http://codepen.io/mcdorli/pen/LkdoZo)

Comment: let me play around with WebGL.  It might be easier to do what you say.  I'll need some days, if not weeks to poke around (very busy here)

Comment: @SMeaden getting into WebGL (or OpenGL in general) is hard. Really hard. Most tutorials has the prerequisite of knowing modern OpenGL

Comment: On first look, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL#Design WebGL is based on Canvas so I presume it is imperative.  I was looking for something declarative.  Still looking.

Comment: @SMeaden if you want a declarative way, then use Three.js

Comment: Oh, that's lovely.  https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes